# Filtering special characters in to_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103880/escaping-special-characters-in-to-tsquery) and [here](http://postgresql.nabble.com/to-tsquery-plainto-avoiding-bad-input-injections-Is-there-a-builtin-function-for-this-Escaping-td1913572.html). I want to provide full-text support using postgreSQL via `to_tsquery`. However, since escaping characters leads to complications, I think it is okay to simply filtering special characters that could provoke errors.

What are the characters I need to remove to use to_tsquery safely. So far, I have identified the following:

1. Input that contains `&`, `|`, `:` might produce syntax errors
2. Input with `*` might not work as expected (`to_tsquery('a*b')` produces 'b')
3. quotes need to be escaped

What do you suggest in order to take user input in `to_tsquery`? What are other special characters I need to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to just leave it as users enter it, since you can safely use strings processed twice via `quote_literal`. In the `to_tsquery` documentation, the example for phrases within ts queries is:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('''supernovae stars'' & !crab');
```

Adding some junk to the phrase breaks it, unless you pass it twice via quote_literal, which makes any string safe to use:

```
SELECT to_tsquery(quote_literal(quote_literal('supernovae '':|stars')) || ' & !crab');
```

Comment: Thanks. I was playing with your last query but I can't figure out why you need to use quote_literal twice: Depending on what meant, this `SELECT to_tsquery(quote_literal('supernovae '':|stars' || ' & !crab'));` and this `SELECT to_tsquery(quote_literal('supernovae '':|stars') || ' & !crab');` works. The only issue I can see is that `quote_literal` doesn't allow me to use the `|` operator instead of `&` and that quoting needs to be used correctly (as you did, in your example, with `''`).

Answer (score 1):

> *Input that contains &, |, : might produce syntax errors*

Use [`plainto_tsquery()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES) instead of `to_tsquery()`.
It's meant to accept free-form user input.

> *Input with * might not work as expected (`to_tsquery('a*b')` produces 'b')*

The text configuration matters. For instance,

```
select to_tsquery('simple','a*b');
 to_tsquery 
 ------------
  'a' & 'b'

select to_tsquery('english','a*b');
 to_tsquery 
------------
 'b'
```

> *quotes need to be escaped*

The same as with any text literal.

Or they don't need to be escaped if using prepared or parametrized statements with `$N`-style parameters, if your
client-side environment supports that.

Comment: Thank you. The issue with `plainto_tsquery()` is that it inserts the `&` operator and as far I know, that can't be changed. I think it is better if I use `|` instead.  Yes, I'm using parameterized statements.